# Coreplot plotspace different ios 5 vs ios 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, core-plot

Running the same code on both, I end up with different results. After checking the plotranges, the actual values are identical, but it results in a cut-off graph in ios 5, where ios 6 looks fine. If I add a bunch of padding on the right side of the plot space, I can make it look fine in ios 5, but then there's extra whitespace in ios 6.

I am running coreplot 1.2, installed using the compiled .a and header files included in the download.

The code:

```
 //fill plot space!
[graph.defaultPlotSpace scaleToFitPlots:graph.allPlots];

CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];

if(_xRange)
    [xRange setLength:[_xRange decimalValue]];

axisSet.xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = yRange.location;
axisSet.yAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = xRange.location;

plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
plotSpace.yRange = yRange;

NSLog(@"PLOTSPACE X: %@ Y:%@",plotSpace.xRange,plotSpace.yRange);

// ios 5 result: <<CPTPlotRange: 0x28ecc0> {1364792400, 5616000}> Y:<<CPTPlotRange: 0x28f0f0> {0, 451}>
//ios 6 results: <<CPTPlotRange: 0x1f5c6090> {1364792400, 5616000}> Y:<<CPTPlotRange: 0x1f5c64d0> {0, 451}>
```

The Graph in ios 6:

[image: the graph looks fine in ios 6]

The Graph in ios 5 (if it isn't clear, it's cut off right about where the last tick mark would be):

[image: The graph on ios 5 is cut off]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known issue with 1.2. Upgrading to the latest version (pull the source with Mercurial) should fix it.